# Can't call custom return component and state updating methods in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've subcomponent named homeMessage which contains the form and with one input tag.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from './SignUp';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: ''
    };
  }
  inputData = (event) =>
  {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  }
  submitData = (event) =>
  {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render(){
    let homeMessage = () =>
    {
      return(
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
            FirstName:
            <input type="text" name="firstName" onChange={this.inputData}/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <Link to="/src/SignUp">SignUp</Link>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return(
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={homeMessage}/>
          <Route path="/src/SignUp" render={(props)=><SignUp firstName={this.state.firstName}/>}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

When I write content of homeMessage contents in original return method it works fine but when I create custom return component like above on every keystroke it removes my cursor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `homeMessage` sub component's definition to this -

```
const homeMessage = (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          FirstName:
          <input type="text" name="firstName" onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <Link to="/src/SignUp">SignUp</Link>
      </div>
  );
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Fat arrow is accepted. The issue was not with the fat arrow. It's how you have defined the element.

Comment: Can you do a favor, please mention the same with fat arrow function? Because, when I normally render like only text or something like that it doesn't creating any problems!